# Why does calling SystemParametersInfo from Rust to set the wallpaper set it to black?

Tags: winapi, rust, wallpaper

I am trying to set the Windows background in Rust using the winapi crate and `SystemParametersInfo`, but it sets the background to black. In C++, that usually means that `pvParam` isn't passed correctly or it has the wrong type. 
What's wrong?

```rust
#[cfg(windows)]
extern crate winapi;

use winapi::ctypes::c_void;

use winapi::um::winuser::{SystemParametersInfoA, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE, SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER};

fn main() {
    let mut image_path = "Path to Image";
    let image_path_c_ptr: *mut c_void = &mut image_path as *mut _ as *mut c_void;

    unsafe {
        SystemParametersInfoA(
            SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,
            0,
            image_path_c_ptr,
            SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE,
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really your question but there is already a crate for setting wallpapers that you could look : https://github.com/reujab/wallpaper.rs

Comment: Hey, thanks I'll take a look at this since I still need to figure out how to set the wallpaper for different monitors
Edit: Ahh damnit the crate supports only one monitor as well ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust strings are not C strings. You should instead use [`CString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html) to interface with C code:

```rust
use std::ffi::CString;

// use ...

fn main() {
    let mut image_path = CString::new("Path to Image").unwrap();

    unsafe {
        SystemParametersInfoA(
            SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,
            0,
            image_path.as_ptr() as *mut c_void,
            SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE,
        );
    }
}
```

To elaborate: `image_path` is a `&str` (a fat pointer). By taking a mutable reference to it you are getting a `&mut &str`. You then pass it to C, which will dereference the pointer and get a `&str`.

But C code does not know how to deal with a Rust type: it is only aware of C strings and instead expects a pointer to the first byte. It also expects the string to be `NUL` terminated, which Rust strings are not. Thus it makes no sense to pass a Rust `&str` to C code in this case and this is exactly the reason `CStr` and `CString` exist.

Comment: Hey thanks. It works now. You got the CString types a little wrong though, I added the working code in my question.

Comment: Another question, do you by any chance know if I can set the background for different screens individually with SystemParametersInfo?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't really worked with WINAPI so I can not comment on the specifics of it. As for types, I think `CStr` should work as you have a static string anyway, no?

Comment: The compiler complained whne using your code.
I looked up the CStr Docs and the example was using CString::new()

Comment: An explicit cast is perhaps needed so I added that.

Comment: The compiler complained about the Cstr::from() part

Comment: "which will dereference the pointer and get a &str" no it's completely UB

Comment: @Stargateur not sure why that would be UB: taking a mutable reference to a `&'static str` and dereferencing it again [is a perfectly safe action](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9cc7540a3215b61dde9b64a80f470ef5). Does the FFI play into this somehow?

Comment: the memory model of fat pointer is unspecified and so you can't know what happen on C side you said "You then pass it to C", So UB if one use it in any context on C side, you can't pass a fat pointer to C It's a Rust only object type.

Comment: Oh you are talking about `&mut &str` not `&str`, well still UB to use `&str` but nevermind

Answer (score 0):

This was my final working code:

```rust
#[cfg(windows)]
extern crate winapi;

use std::ffi::CString;
use winapi::ctypes::c_void;

use winapi::um::winuser::{SystemParametersInfoA, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE, SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER};

fn main() {
    let mut image_path = CString::new("Path to Image").unwrap();

    unsafe {
        SystemParametersInfoA(
            SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,
            0,
            image_path.as_ptr() as *mut c_void,
            SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE,
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: test failed in Windows 10 OS build 19044.1645, with winapi 0.3.9, the wallpaper was set to black...